# STM32 Discovery dev platforms

Tags: audio, dsp-core, analog-to-digital, arm

I'm still researching this but though I'd post asking about experiences. Looks like st.com offers a variety of STM32 Discovery dev boards for ARM CPUs to, among other things, play with DSP. But searching this forum didn't find much.

Ideally I'd like something with built-in stereo ADC/DAC but I don't seem to see that. I see daughter boards that have stereo mics and stereo outputs. But mics are a non-starter for me. I need line level inputs.

Or this video recommends a Wolfson board which you splice to the STM32.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO66UN64-os

What's the difference of the M7 core over the M4? Where to order?  How do you power the board?

Thanks.

Dennis

Comment: This would be a better question for [electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).